# How to move a char from the subdomain to the filename in Apache mod rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this URL:

```
http://hostX.site.com/some_path_here/filename.jpg
```

and need to rewrite it to:

```
http://host.site.com/same_path_here/filenameX.jpg
```

Can you please tell me if this is possible?
Basically I am trying to move "**X**" (it is a number) from the subdomain to the end of the filename, just before the extension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host(\d)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)\.([^/.]+)$ http://host.example.com/$1%1.$2
```

But since the host is different, this will cause an external redirect.

Answer (score 2):

(Without testing,) something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} host(\d).site.com
RewriteRule (.*)\.(.*) host.site.com/$1%1.$2
```

You need to extract the host number through the RewriteCond. In the RewriteRule you can use the number with the %-modifier

HTH